# What is the link between permittivity, thickness and optical path length (OPL) of a sample?

Tags: optics, models

I am reading this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9946401/) regarding cornea phantom sensing using THz radiation.

In this paper, the authors propose using a bunch of modelling and to measure a bunch of spheres of different radius of curvature (RoC) to compare to the the results obtained from measuring an imperfectly hemispherical sample.

It is stated in the paper that

"When the extracted permittivity increases, the extracted thickness decreases, thus suggesting a conservation in OPL."

Why is this the case? How are these 3 quantities linked?